# Can't Access configparser environment variables from env.ini file in faust (kafka streaming)

Tags: python, environment-variables, fastapi, configparser, faust

My Project is on FastAPI and the structure goes like this.

```
- project
   - app
      - kafka_layer
          - faustworker.py
   - core
      - configs.py
   - env.ini
```

My env.ini file goes like this

```
[DEFAULT]
DATABASE_URL=url_to_db
```

I've tried adding this code in configs.py

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("env.ini")
```

I want to access environment variables in faustworker.py using this code

```
from app.core.configs import config
db_url = config['DEFAULT']['DATABASE_URL']
```

When I tried using the instance of config in faustworker.py, it returned ***KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run faust worker in a docker container going to the folder

eg:

```
cd app
cd kafka_layer
faust -A faust_worker
```

But What I needed to do is

```
faust -A app.kafka_layer.faust_worker
```

It works totally fine now. :)